# Changing CSS using jQuery in SharePoint List

Tags: javascript, custom-list, css

I want to change the CSS using jQuery if a certain statement returns true. I have been just playing around without the statement but it doesn't seem to work.
This is my js file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
window.SFW = window.SFW || {};
window.SFW.urgentAlertsItem = {
customItemHtml: function (ctx) {


    var urgentAlertsItemHtml = "<div class='urgent'><h2 class='name'>" + ctx.CurrentItem.Title + "</h2>";
    urgentAlertsItemHtml += "<div class='note'>" + ctx.CurrentItem.Note+ "</div>";
    urgentAlertsItemHtml += "<div class='severity'>" + ctx.CurrentItem.Severity+ "</div>";
    urgentAlertsItemHtml += "<div class='profile'> <img src='" + ctx.CurrentItem.Profile+"' /></div>";
    urgentAlertsItemHtml += "<button class ='moreDet'>More Detail</button></div>";
    return urgentAlertsItemHtml;
}
};

// anonymous self-executing function to setup JSLink templates on page load..
(function () {
var overrideCtx = {};
overrideCtx.Templates = {};

overrideCtx.Templates.Header = "<div id='urg'>";
overrideCtx.Templates.Item = window.SFW.urgentAlertsItem.customItemHtml;
overrideCtx.Templates.Footer = "</div>";

overrideCtx.BaseViewID = 1;
overrideCtx.ListTemplateType = 100;

SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideCtx);
})();


// JavaScript source code
$(document).ready(function () {


        $(".severity").css("color: blue"); 

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax is either

`$(".severity").css({"color" : "blue"});`

OR

`$(".severity").css("color", "blue");`

The first syntax is used mostly to edit multiple css properties (separated by comma).

[Source](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct syntax

```
$(".severity").css("color", "blue");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always combine an if statement to check if a value is true before it executes the css color change.

```
if (statement) { //if the statement is true
     $(".severity").css("color", "blue");
}
```